# Regular Expression Issue Pattern not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a regular expression which accepts only an email with the following pattern.

@stanford.edu.uk or word.edu.word

here it is

`/(\.edu\.\w\w\w?)$/`

It appears that this only works when .edu is followed by ".xx" (example: school.edu.au or college.edu.uk). I need this to also work for e-mails that end with .edu (example: school.edu or student.college.edu)

I tried this:

```
/(\.w+\.w+\.edu)$/
```

If any one can help?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression

Comment: Try [`\.edu(?:\.\w{2,3})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/N81HS4/2)

Comment: Im gonna try Wiktor's regex.

Comment: Waoo awesome! your answer worked!

Comment: This is a great website for figuring out if your regex will work. https://regex101.com/

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting/upvoting [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50941797/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `(\.edu\.\w\w\w?)$` pattern requires a `.` and at 2 to 3 word chars after it before the end of the string, so it can't match strings with `.edu` at the end.

You may fix the pattern using

```
\.edu(?:\.\w{2,3})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N81HS4/2)

**Details**

- `\.edu` - an `.edu` substring
- `(?:\.\w{2,3})?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\w{2,3}` - 2 to 3 word chars
- `$` - end of string.

Note that `\w` matches letters, digits and `_`. You might want to precise this bit in case you only want to match letters (`[a-zA-Z]` to only handle ASCII, or use ECMAScript 2018 powered `\p{L}` Unicode property class (not working in older browsers), or build your own [pattern to support all Unicode letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes)).

Also, consider going through [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323)